# How to have autogrow children with flexbox?

Tags: height, flexbox

I have:

```
    <style>
        .parent{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
        }
        .c1{
            flex: 1 100%;
            background: green;
        }
        .c2{
            flex: 1;
            background: red;
        }
        .c3{
            flex: 4;
            background: cyan;
        }
    </style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="c1">100% width</div>
    <div class="c2">This text is big and long, and pushes the other div towards the bottom of the page and blabla.</div>
    <div class="c3">This should not grow.</div>
</div>
```

And I wonder if it is posible to have the cyan div not to have 100%. A fixed size doesn't look right because I want it to grow with the flow of text in diferent window sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
align-items: flex-start;
```

to the parent div. This makes the children align top and have diferent sizes. Strangely, the default valu for align-items is stretch.